# Sum of topological charges is the Euler characteristic

Tags: topology, solitons, topological-defects

I have seen many places claiming that the given a collection of topological defects on a 2-dimensional surface, the sum of the topological charges is $2\pi\chi$ (where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic).

What is the proof of this statement? Can you give me any references for the general case (not in a special case, like liquid crystals)? If not, what is the proof for ordinary 2 dimensional crystals?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't explain what you mean by "topological charges" but I expect you  mean the sum of the Hopf indices of the zeros  of a tangent-vector field on a manifold. The resulting
[Poincare-Hopf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem) theorem  says that the sum of these numbers is indeed $\chi$.

A discussion and sketch of a proof can be found  starting on on page 547 of my book with Paul Goldbart  *Mathematics for Physics*,  an online  draft version of which can be found  [here](https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf).